I can't configure webhook url for whatsapp cloud API
I'm trying to configure the webhook. I watched a lot of videos using platforms like Heroku or ngrok. But I already have a server, Hostinger Brasil. The problem is that the URL I put in the configuration is not accepted. I don't know if it's because of my code or some configuration I didn't do.
"Port" 80 is the web standard, but I still wanted to specify it. On localhost, testing, it only works on port 8000, 3000.
Basically, I understood a little how to configure the webhook in javascript. But how to generate a url that Meta checks? When I testing on localhost it works. But generating the url with the .js file doesn't work. Do you have any configuration on Hostinger? Does the file need php or html? I don't understand this part about servers, if someone can explain it to me, I would be very grateful.
Sorry for my English :/
arquivo .env
WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN = "123"
GRAPH_API_TOKEN = "EAAQUA14XZBPwBO7M7sqU46sO7eSbVjYQAGJiD9rqOnOhTLIUyPPZBT2SZAbJLzOPUIGZAblwp5TiwWsPe1AgxuGtiZAJlumDrZBXH7ROct5IDZCOmJXji8OWUnfQPFrmmI3LTCkPjJygkmyx2MmtPXKp9KFcAGVRoLErlMKQl2JbFBjAi8KDyDe2rgQ9ouGd37PAozBALTQ1B48jpKYbZBUZD"   # token temporary
PORT = 80

arquivo index.js
    // ------ IMPORTANDO MODULOS
const express = require("express");         // framework para aplicativos web do Node.js
const body_parser = require("body-parser"); // middleware para analisar corpos de solicitação em middleware antes de seus manipuladores
const axios = require("axios");             // biblioteca HTTP cliente para fazer requisições HTTP
require('dotenv').config();                 // módulo para carregar variáveis de ambiente do arquivo .env


// configuracao do Express. Criamos uma instância do aplicativo Express e usamos o body_parser.json() para analisar os corpos das solicitações como JSON
const app = express().use(body_parser.json());


const token = process.env.GRAPH_API_TOKEN;   //temporary access token dashboard api wpp
const mytoken = process.env.WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN;


// inicia o servidor Express na porta 8000 ou na porta definida em process.env.PORT

app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
  console.log("webhook is listening...");
})


app.get("/",(req,res) => {
  res.status(200).send("hello this is webhook setup");
});


// é definida uma rota GET para a URL /webhook que será usada para verificação e configuração do webhook do Facebook
// para verificar a url de retorno no painel de apps (cloud api)
app.get("/webhook", (req, res) =>{
  let mode = req.query["hub.mode"];
  let token = req.query["hub.verify_token"];
  let challenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];  

  // check the mode and token sent are correct
  if (mode && token) {
    if(mode === "subscribe" && token === mytoken){
      // respond with 200 OK and challenge token from the request
      res.status(200).send(challenge);
      console.log("Webhook verified successfully!");
    }else {
      // respond with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }
  } 
});


// trata as solicitações POST recebidas no endpoint /webhook, onde as mensagens recebidas do WhatsApp serão processadas e respondidas
app.post("/webhook",(req,res) => {
  let body_param = req.body;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(body_param,null,2)); // obtem a resposta e coloca no console

  // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/payload-examples
  if(body_param.object){
    if(body_param.entry &&  // Verifica se a propriedade entry existe em body_param e se não é null ou undefined
      body_param.entry[0].changes &&  // Verifica se o primeiro elemento do array entry possui a propriedade changes e se não é null ou undefine
      body_param.entry[0].changes[0].value.message && // Verifica se o primeiro elemento do array changes possui a propriedade value com uma subpropriedade message e se não é null ou undefined
      body_param.entry[0].changes[0].value.message[0] // Verifica se o primeiro elemento do array message existe.
    ){
      let phone_no_id = body_param.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id;
      let from =        body_param.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from;
      let msg_body =    body_param.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].text.body;
    
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        // acha em https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1147904602929404/whatsapp-business/wa-dev-console/?business_id=969071548077814
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/"+phone_no_id+"/messages?access_token="+token, 
        data: {
          messaging_product: "whatsapp",
          to: from,
          text:{
            body: "Hi..."
          }
        },
        headers:{
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      })

      res.sendStatus(200);
    }else{
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  }
});


I've also tried putting the URL in the "user" of the webhook, but it wasn't accepted.


You can check and debug your webhook before adding it to the app, try to call it from Postman and pass the token, and debug.

HTTPS is required for web hook & in past I tried to use custom ports that also did not work. May be this helps

@MrMegamind, I used https and it still didn't work :/
